# ReactJs (ES6) : Render component from a function

Tags: reactjs

**My code**

```
class Box extends Component {


    render () {

        return(
            <div className="box" style={styles.box}>
                <div className="img-container" style={styles}>
                    <img alt="Brand Logo" src={this.props.data.brand_logo} className="img-circle" id="brand_logo" width="50"/>
                </div>
                <ul className="box-basic-info-container">
                    <li>{basic_info_keys[0]} : {basic_info[basic_info_keys[0]]}</li>
                    <li>{basic_info[basic_info_keys[1]]}</li>
                </ul>
                {
                    iconEllipsis
                }
                <div className="box-other-info-container" >
                    <ul className="other_info" style={styles.contactInfo} >
                        {
                            other_info_keys.map(function(item,i){
                                return (<li key={i}>{item}: {other_info[item]}</li>)
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {this.renderManagerModal()}
            </div>
        )



    }
    renderManagerModal = () =>{
        return (
                <div>
                    <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
                        <Modal.Header closeButton>
                            <Modal.Title>Managers</Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                        </Modal.Body>
                        <Modal.Footer>
                            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
                        </Modal.Footer>
                    </Modal>
                </div>
        )



    }
}
```

I am new to ES6 syntax.
I have used this in ES5.
But this is not working in ES6.

`this.renderthisManagerModal` is returning an empty div

Why is it so ?
How to write a function that returns a component ?
I dont want to import from different file.
I want to write the component in the same file .

Comment: Where is your `state` defined? i see your modal's appearance depends on `this.state.showModal`. Where do you define and update it ?

Comment: It is defined. 
My problem is modal is not displayed in the DOM structure when i see it in the console .

Comment: What happens if you render just some plain html inside `renderManagerModal` method? If it works, then it is something about your `Modal` Component, not `Box` Component.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, however I would encourage you to make use of the components in react. It's clean and you can make sure to have a separation of concerns.

I'd like to comment but my reputation is too low. Tell me, does this work?

```
 renderManagerModal = () => {
        return (
                <div>
                    Test
                </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good approach would be to put renderManagerModal in a pure component like this:

```
  //assuming your props are coming from the Box component
  const RenderManagerModal = (props) => {
        return (
                <div>

                    <Modal show={props.showModal} onHide={props.close}>
                        <Modal.Header closeButton>
                            <Modal.Title>Managers</Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                        </Modal.Body>
                        <Modal.Footer>
                            <Button onClick={props.close}>Close</Button>
                        </Modal.Footer>
                    </Modal>
                </div>
        )
    }
```

Then you would put that component inside the Box component like below:

```
class Box extends Component {

    showModal(){} 

    close{}

    render () {

        return(
            <div className="box" style={styles.box}>
                <div className="img-container" style={styles}>
                    <img alt="Brand Logo" src={this.props.data.brand_logo} className="img-circle" id="brand_logo" width="50"/>
                </div>
                <ul className="box-basic-info-container">
                    <li>{basic_info_keys[0]} : {basic_info[basic_info_keys[0]]}</li>
                    <li>{basic_info[basic_info_keys[1]]}</li>
                </ul>
                {
                    iconEllipsis
                }
                <div className="box-other-info-container" >
                    <ul className="other_info" style={styles.contactInfo} >
                        {
                            other_info_keys.map(function(item,i){
                                return (<li key={i}>{item}: {other_info[item]}</li>)
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <RenderManagerModal showModal={this.showModal} onHide={this.close}/>
            </div>
        )

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using arrow function when running `renderManagerModal` so the lexical `this` is the scope of the `renderManagerModal`, not the modal itself. To keep `this` you have to use "old" function declaration `function () {}`